# Настройка fcgi nginx perl

Tags: nginx, perl

Настроил nginx по [этой](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/nginx-and-perlfastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/#install-required-packages) инструкции.
Вроде работает, однако запросы выстраиваются в очередь, те если открыть две вкладки то вторая не загрузится, пока не загрузится первая.
Когда настраивал php там php-fpm все разруливал, а как быть с перлом? Есть что-то подобное?

Comment: А у вкладок одинаковый урл?

Comment: Да, одинаковый.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте добавить во второй вкладке какой-нибудь бессмысленный параметр типа `?x=1` что бы урлы не совпадали. Скорее всего проблема не в настройках nginx, а том что браузер «надеется» что ответ на второй запрос можно будет взять из кеша. В таком случае надо настраивать заголовки кеширования в приложении.

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело. С php-то все нормально отрабатывает. Там процессы разруливает fpm. Тут, наверное, должен этим заниматься  spawn-fcgi или еще какой демон.
На всякий случай ваш вариант тоже проверил. Не то.

Comment: Так может надо циферку в `FCGI_CHILDREN="1"` поменять?

Comment: Да нет, не про то эта циферка. Но проверил, не то.